Does there exist a functor from commutative rings to commutative rings that takes the poset of prime ideals to its opposite?
According to the following questions:

Is every poset the poset of prime ideals of a ring?
Partial orders that can be realized by prime ideals of commutative rings
Partial Orders realized by Prime Ideals on commutative rings

we have the following criterion for a poset $P$ being the poset of prime ideals of a commutative ring with unity $R$:

Theorem (Hochster, Proposition 12 of this paper): Let $P$ be a poset.  Then $P$ is isomorphic to the poset of prime ideals of a commutative ring iff it is order-isomorphic to a closed subset of $\{0,1\}^V$ for some set $V$ (putting the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$ and the product topology on $\{0,1\}^V$, and the usual order on $\{0,1\}$ and the product order on $\{0,1\}^V$).

From this criterion, it is clear that if $P$ has this property, $P^{\operatorname{op}}$ also has this property.
Now consider the following assignment: Given a commutative ring $R$, let $P$ be the poset of its prime ideals. Let $P' = P^{\operatorname{op}}$. By the above, there is some commutative ring $R'$ whose poset of prime ideals is $P'$.
Question: Can this assignment of objects be made in a functorial manner? Meaning, does there exist a functor $F: \mathsf{CRing} \to \mathsf{CRing}$ such that the poset of prime ideals of $F(R)$ is the opposite of the poset of prime ideals of $R$?

I would check if you can get a functor from these posets to commutative rings, inverting Spec. The introduction in Hochster's paper says Proving that these properties characterize the image of Spec involves constructing
a large number of rings. This construction (§§3-7) is very intricate, but is practically
choice-free and turns out to be fairly functorial.

@MartinBrandenburg Thanks for making me think about simply looking at Hochster's paper. In fact it seems like he addresses my very question in his article! I'll try to write this up as an answer.

Thanks to @MartinBrandenburg for giving me the idea to simply look at Hochster's paper. In fact, he addresses my question exactly. Hochster's article is [1].
In the introduction, Hochster writes:

0. Introduction. Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the category of commutative rings with unit, and regard $\operatorname{Spec}$ as a contravariant functor from $\mathscr{C}$ to $\mathscr{T}$, the category of topological spaces and continuous maps. The spaces of the form $\operatorname{Spec} A$, $A$ a ring, are well known to have many special properties. It is worthwhile to discover whether these well-known properties of the spaces characterize them, since we then will know the limitations of the topological approach. As a by-product of this study, remarkable facts about the structure of the prime ideals in a commutative ring come to light. E.g. given any ring $A$ there is a ring whose prime ideals have precisely the reverse order of the primes of $A$. In the same vein, on the topological level there is a complete duality between localization and taking residue class rings.

Around Proposition 8, Hochster now addresses the question:

We now obtain the topological duality mentioned in the introduction.
Proposition 8. Let $X$ be spectral. Retopologize $X$ by taking as a basis for the closed sets the quasi-compact open sets of $X$. Then $X$ with this new topology is spectral, and the new order induced on $X$ by this topology is precisely the reverse of the original order.
Proof. The patch space of $X$ with this new topology is clearly identical with the patch space of $X$ with the original topology, and $X$ in the new topology has a sub-basis for its open sets consisting of sets which are compact open in the patch topology. The new topology is clearly $T_0$, and it follows from Proposition 7 that $X$ with the new topology is spectral. The fact that the order is reversed is obvious.
9. The patch functor. If $X$ is spectral, let $T(X)$ be the patch space of $X$, and if $f: X \to X'$ is spectral, let $T(f)$ be the corresponding map (same graph) from $T(X)$ to $T(X')$. $T$ is a covariant functor from $\mathscr{S}$ onto $\mathscr{K}$, the full subcategory of $\mathscr{T}$ whose objects are the totally disconnected compact spaces (equivalently, $\mathscr{K}$ is the full subcategory of $\mathscr{S}$ whose objects are the $T_1$ spectral spaces). $T$ is the "patch functor".
Let $J$ be the inclusion functor of $\mathscr{K}$ in $\mathscr{S}$. $TJ$ is the identity functor on $\mathscr{K}$. Moreover, $T$ is adjoint to $J$ ($J$ is coadjoint to $T$). This follows from the obvious one-one correspondence between spectral maps from $J(Y)$ to $X$ ($Y$, $X$ given objects of $\mathscr{K}$, $\mathscr{S}$ respectively) and continuous ($\Rightarrow$ spectral) maps from $Y$ to $T(X)$.
In the next section we show that this situation can be lifted, as it were, to $\mathscr{C}$. An interesting class of ring epimorphisms is brought to light. However, the adjointness of the functors is lost in the lifting.
10. A class of ring epimorphisms. Let $\mathscr{D}$ be the full subcategory of $\mathscr{C}$ whose objects are the rings without radical whose spectra are $T_1$ spaces, i.e. all of whose prime ideals are maximal. Up to isomorphisms, $\operatorname{Spec}$ maps $\mathscr{C}$ onto $\mathscr{K}$. Let $J'$ be the inclusion functor of $\mathscr{D}$ in $\mathscr{C}$. $J'$ lifts $J$ in the sense that $\operatorname{Spec} J' \cong J \operatorname{Spec}$, as functors. We want to define a functor from $\mathscr{C}$ to $\mathscr{D}$ which lifts $T$ similarly. Let $A$ be a ring with $\operatorname{Spec} A = X$. For each $x \in C$, let $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} k_x = \left(\quotient{A}{x}\right)^{\ast}$. Let $T'(A)$ be the subring of $\prod_{x \in X} k_x$ consisting of elements $b$ such that for each $x \in X$ there is a patch neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and elements $a_1$, $a_2$ of $A$ such that for all $y \in U$, $a_2$ is not in $y$ (regarded as an ideal) and $b(y) = \frac{\psi_y(a_1)}{\psi_y(a_2)}$, where $\psi_y$ is the canonical homomorphism $A \to k_y$. It is a straightforward matter to verify that $T'(A)$ is an object of $\mathscr{D}$ and that its spectrum may be identified in a natural way with $T(X)$.
This brings us to the class of epimorphisms. The obvious homomorphism $h_A: A \to T'(A)$ is an epimorphism, because $\operatorname{Spec} h_A$ (which may be identified with $1_X: T(X) \to X$) is injective, and the induced maps of local rings ($A_x \to k_x$) are epimorphisms, in fact, surjections. Here, we only note the curious fact that in the case where $A$ is the integers, $h_A$ is an epimorphism from the integers to a ring which is not Noetherian.
We next observe that if $h: A \to B$ is a ring homomorphism, then there is a unique homomorphism $T'(h): T'(A) \to T'(B)$ such that $T'(h) h_A = h_B h$, and such that $\operatorname{Spec} T'(h)$ has the same graph as $\operatorname{Spec} h$ when $\operatorname{Spec} T'(A)$, $\operatorname{Spec} T'(B)$ are identified with $T(\operatorname{Spec} A)$, $T(\operatorname{Spec} B)$, respectively. This defines $T'$ as a functor, and we then have $\operatorname{Spec}T' = T \operatorname{Spec}$. Moreover, $T'J'$ is the identity on $\mathscr{D}$. This completes our discussion of the lifting.

This means that $T'$ is exactly the functor which I asked about in my question.

[1]:
Hochster, M. (1969). Prime ideal structure in commutative rings. Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 142, 43–43. doi:10.1090/s0002-9947-1969-0251026-x
https://doi.org/10.1090/s0002-9947-1969-0251026-x

What an interesting read!

You copied some sections of the paper but unfortunately it's not self-contained. In the end one has to check the paper to understand what is going on and also for the definitions of some things. I am not sure, maybe it is better to either make it self-contained, or just reduce the answer to the link and the quote in the beginning.

@MartinBrandenburg Yes, the whole preceding topological discussion is somehow a prerequisite. I don't really know how to improve this. I think the algebraic construction at the end is pretty self-contained though (except for the proof that it actually reverses the order).
